# What namespace and I missing for Serilog?

Tags: serilog

I am able to use LoggerConfiguration() in my C# code with various Serilog Sinks but my compiler is complaining about the specification of my use of ".WriteTo.File".  I am confused because I have ben able to use this specification in another demo solution.  I wonder if there is some sort of Assembly I need to add as a reference.  I have run "Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File" from the "Package Manager Console" but that did not seem to have any effect or change.
[image]
What directive am I missing or what assembly reference do I need?
[image]
I tried to figure this out via online documentation but I can not find the result.

Comment: @CaioProiete this one is the original post; please put close votes on the other one instead

Answer (score 2):

You are not missing a namespace. You are missing a Sink... The [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file).

#### Install the [Serilog.Sinks.File](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.File/) package from NuGet:

```
Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File
```

---

Every time you use `WriteTo`*.Something*, you're writing to a specific sink, which needs to be added to your project.

Here you can see a list of available sinks you can use:
https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Provided-Sinks

Comment: @xarzu I get this appears to ignore your OP. The way to fix that problem is with a comment - the author regularly writes detailed and helpful posts, confirming to people that _SELECT is not broken_ (as my answer here says https://stackoverflow.com/a/55270539/11635). A downvote with no comment solves no problems for anyone

Comment: Already mention in question that he `Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File`