# What namespace am I missing for Serilog?

Tags: serilog

What namspace and I missing for Serilog?

I am able to use LoggerConfiguration() in my C# code with various Serilog Sinks but my compiler is complaining about the specification of my use of ".WriteTo.File". I am confused because I have ben able to use this specification in another demo solution. I wonder if there is some sort of Assembly I need to add as a reference. I have run "Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.File" from the "Package Manager Console" but that did not seem to have any effect or change.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/frjM5.png]

What directive am I missing or what assembly reference do I need?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xUTC.png]

I tried to figure this out via online documentation but I can not find the result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What namespace and I missing for Serilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266385/what-namespace-and-i-missing-for-serilog)

Comment: Please don't [double post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55266385/what-namspace-and-i-missing-for-serilog) - it's very rude (as is downvoting people trying to help you without leaving a comment as to what they've done to offend you so)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to be

```
using Serilog;
```

The message you've shown suggests there's been some problem with the processing off the `Add-Package`, which seems correct in outline - I'd be checking the NuGet references and seeing whether it's actually been applied; it's not going to work without it.